# Preserve keys after calling to preg_split

Tags: php, arrays, key

I'm using preg_match for performing a regular expression match, but before using it I declared my array with specific keys as follows:

```
$record = array ( "title"         => '',
                  "review"        => '',
                  "publisher"     => '',
                );
```

and here I call the function

```
$record = preg_split( "/(\s\|\s)|(\s\|)/", $data, 4 );
```

If I try to use the array with

```
echo $record['title'];
```

I got the following message error:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: title
```

Is there a way to preserve my keys?

Comment: `$record = array_combine(array_keys($record), preg_split(...));`

Comment: OK, perfect, it works! Thank you, I'm newbie with php.

Comment: [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) will return an array with the matches and it doesn't *fill up* your defined array. It will just overwrite it. So with [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) you combine the matches with your array and can create an associative array